# Regex: Substring start with a text

Tags: regex, substring

i have trouble to extract a error message. My error message start with **error:** and i want to have the text after the **error:** to the end of the line.

Can anybody help my please?

example:
`error: my error text`

I wanna extract 
`my error text`

I'm only able to select the whole line.

Thanks in advance
Tonka

Comment: Use a capture group then: `^error:\s*(.*)$` - https://regex101.com/r/zS6sZ0/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not specify what language you are using, you can use lookbehind.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lA6wI4/1)

`(?<=error: )(.*)`

This looks for lines starting with "`error:`", and matches everything that follows afterwards. This will match a single line though.

Comment: at the moment i've only try it with regexr.com, but i will use the regex in python 3 and c++ (boost/Qt)

Comment: ok. lookbehind is the trick and it is not supported by regexr.com. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If your messages always start with `error:` you might as well just use substring. You didn't say which language you were using, but this would do the trick in javascript :

```
message.substring(7)
```

Comment: that is what i'm doing now. Extract the error line and remove the error:text. But I thought that is possible with one regex call.

Comment: It sure is, but it might however be less efficient